# How to solve Couldn't import django error?

Tags: windows, anaconda, atom-editor

**Help me** 
I am using anaconda with windows 10

What I have done:

```
conda create --name Mydjango django

cd desktop

mkdir Projects

cd Projects

Activate Mydjango

Django-admin startproject first-project
```

When I open manage.py I get an error. Says couldn't import django......

Comment: Could you please share with us what is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: The correct command to create the environment would be `conda create --name Mydjango python=3.7 django`. (Substitute `3.7` for the Python version you want.)

Comment: @orangeInk there's nothing incorrect with using just `django` - Python will get pulled in as a dependency of it. Your command is only needed if one wants to specify a Python version other than the latest.

Comment: @merv I just tested it and you're absolutely right. I've had similar problems in past with not passing `python=...` to the create command and just figured that that's the problem here. I don't know if conda changed since I had my problems or if I'm just remembering it wrong, anyway thanks for clearing that up.